# How can I set the position of text along path in tikz more precisely?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, decorations

## Explanation

It seems that nodes can be carefully placed on paths using `pos=.25` (i.e. 25% from node BEGIN to node END) when using `--` syntax (see Example A).

## Problem

I cannot have the same precision as above with paths constructed using the `to` syntax (see Example B.). Instead, I have resulted to using

```
postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text={|\ttfamily|TCP}}}
```

**Example A.** Note that I can do:

> ```
> \draw [<->] (data.south east) -- (app.north west) 
> node [pos=.5, above, sloped] (TextNode) {TCP};
> ```

**Example B.** Note that I cannot do:

> ```
> \draw [icoarrow,<->] (data.south east) to[out=90,in=270] (app.north west) 
> node [pos=.5, above, sloped] (TextNode) {TCP};
> ```

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.text}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (data) {Data};
    \node [right=of data] (app) {App};
    % Lines
    \draw [<->] (data) -- (app) node [pos=.5, above, sloped] (TextNode) {TCP}; % works fine
    \draw [<->] (data) to[out=90,in=90] (app) node [pos=.5, above, sloped] (TextNode) {TCP}; % does not work
    \draw [<->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={TCP}}}]  (data) to[out=90,in=90] (app); % works fine
    %\draw [<->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,pos=.25,text={TCP}}}]  (data) to[out=90,in=90] (app); % does not work (causes error)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For A:

Put the `node` right after `to[out=90,in=90]` like

```
\draw [<->] (data) to[out=90,in=90]node [pos=.5, above, sloped] (TextNode) {TCP} (app) ;
```

For B, do this:

```
\draw[<->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=1ex,text align=center,text={TCP}}}]   (data) to[out=90,in=90] (app);
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.text}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (data) {Data};
    \node [right=of data] (app) {App};
    % Lines
    \draw [<->] (data) -- (app) node [pos=.5, above, sloped] (TextNode) {TCP}; % works fine
    \draw [<->] (data) to[out=90,in=90]node [pos=.5, above, sloped] (TextNode) {TCP} (app) ; % does not work
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node (data) {Data};
    \node [right=of data] (app) {App};
    % Lines    
    \draw[<->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,raise=1ex,text align=center,text={TCP}}}]   (data) to[out=90,in=90] (app); % does not work (causes error)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why it must be this way?