# overlay latex output on top of VerbatimInput TEXT file

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry

just like [How can I superimpose LaTeX / TeX output over a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/how-can-i-superimpose-latex-tex-output-over-a-pdf-file) **except** I want to write over a **multi-page text file**, brought into my main .tex file with:

```
 \newgeometry{left=3mm,right=5mm}
 VerbatimInput{} 
 \restoregeometry
```

from [Include data from a .txt verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85200/include-data-from-a-txt-verbatim) . Additionally, due to the text file, I also wrapped a margin changer.

If I can write on top of this text with absolute positioning I can't image the margins being a problem.

Other than writing on top of pdfs, or forcing figures on top of each other, I did not see anything useful (at least that I could understand).

Lastly, I would like to write in a different color, but I guess I could just do something like

```
 {\color{blue}{text here}}
```

I didn't provide a MWE because my data file I would like to write upon is long but not really important, and the two links I provided should suffice... I hope!

P.S. I should note that I can get things like this: [How can I set the position of text along path in tikz more precisely?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235360/how-can-i-set-the-position-of-text-along-path-in-tikz-more-precisely) to work - text on a tikz path, but I'm unsure how to do such things, positioned absolutely, for a specific page in a multi-page text file from VerbatimInput. Also, I don't need a path, just normal text...

P.P.S. I guess what an equivalent thing I would like is something like this.

```
 \begin{verbatim}
 copy and pasted text from data file
 \end{verbatim}
 ...at this line, the reason for the above text in the text file is...
 \begin{verbatim}
 continuing copy and paste of data file
 \end{verbatim}
 ...another comment about something in the data file, probably in color
 \begin{verbatim}
 rest of copy and paste of data file
 \end{verbatim}
```

The only problem, which is minor, is that it makes my .tex file long and hard to naviage.

Comment: If you use `listings` package, you can define which lines are included in your text, so you can include comments as regular text between fragments of verbatim code.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly, by doing this:  \lstinputlisting[firstline=1,lastline=5]{file}
comment
\lstinputlisting[firstline=6,lastline=8]{file} If you make it an answer I'll accept it. 
comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstline` and `lastline` options for `listing` (or `lstinputlisting`) commands from `listings` package can be used to display a specific fragment from a listing (code, verbatim, ...). With them there's no need to insert `regular comments` inside a code listing because you can do the other way round: insert `code fragments` inside a regular document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    frame=single
    }

\begin{document}
Preamble follows
\lstinputlisting[firstline=1,lastline=11]{282168.tex}

Document body is shown in next box
\lstinputlisting[firstline=14,lastline=20]{282168.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]